# 13.04 boot problem

Tags: installation, boot, 13.04, hard-drive, bios

I'm trying to install 13.04 on an 80GB IDE HDD.

I've booted from the CD and set sda1 as the primary boot partition using ext4 filesystem and to format/mount as /
I've set sda2 as a small (3GB) swap partition and set the file system as such.

Ubuntu installed okay (said to restart, ejected disc but didn't power itself off so had to power of manually - would that cause the problem?).

I have changed the BIOS back to boot from the HDD but now the BIOS doesn't recognise the HDD and I get 'operating system not found'?

I've already tried the setting 'large disc access' in BIOS (either DOS or other), neither work.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can try boot-repair I get a simmeler problem a lot.

First boot into a live cd and open a terminal and type

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
```

Wait for it to finish then type

```
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

You can now launch boot repair from the dash just follow the instructions on screen.

Here you can find some more info on boot-repair https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair